Table only works with blank row?
I have made the following LaTeX table.

However, to make it work I have had to include the line & & & & & \\. If I remove the line the table adds an additional column...

Here's the code:
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|}

\hline

\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{TEST REPORT}} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Module}} &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{TITLE}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Course}} \\ 

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} & 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2024} \\

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Revision}} &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Page}} \\ 

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Original} & 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1 of 38} \\ 
\hline

\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Prepared by:}} \\ \hline

% ************* Student 1 *************
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Name (Company)}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Date}} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Contact}} \\

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Student 1}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{signature}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{16 Oct 20}} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{name@example.edu}} \\ \hline

% ************* Student 2 *************
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Name (Company)}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Date}} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Contact}} \\

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Student 2}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{signature}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{16 Oct 20}} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{name@example.edu}} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Approved by:}} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Name}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Date}} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Contact}} \\

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Instructor}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{signature}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{23 Oct 20}} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{name@example.edu}} \\ \hline
& & & & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Distribution Statement}} \\

\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Distribution xyz} \\

\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{abcdefg} \\

\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{12345} \\

\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}

What am I doing wrong?

welcome! please complete your code so we have a complete example we can compile. but you are misusing tabularx. in particular, it is generally problematic to use \multicolumn across X type columns. it is not at all obvious why you are using tabularx here. why not tabular? you almost certainly don't want table here either and certainly shouldn't use it with only the h placement option.

Better stay away from these awful online code generators. All these unnecessary \multicolumn will make it very hard to get a nice layout.

@cfr thank you. I edited my question to the packages etc so that someone could easily copy the code and run it. I used tabularx as I wanted the full table width to be 'full width' across the page (i.e. \linewidth) from my understanding this can not be done via the inbuilt tabular, but happy to be corrected on this.

The problem with your code is, that the table without the empty row does not have any real X column. But tabularx needs at least one real X column to calculate the width of the columns. In your case it is very easy, you just need to replace one of your \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{…} or \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{…} by a \multicolumn{6}{|X|}{…}. But this would not increase the natural with of all columns, but only the last column. So it is better to also change some other columns:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|C{1}|X|X|X|X|C{1}|}

  \hline
  \multicolumn{6}{|>{\bfseries}C6|}{TEST REPORT} \\ \hline

  \textbf{Module} \par
  1 \par
  \textbf{Revision} \par
  Original &
  \multicolumn{4}{C4|}{\textbf{TITLE}} &
  \textbf{Course} \par
  1 \par
  \textbf{Page} \par
  1 of 38 \\ 
  \hline

  \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Prepared by:}} \\ \hline

% ************* Student 1 *************
  \multicolumn{2}{|>{\bfseries}C{2}|}{%
    Name (Company)\par
    Student 1} &
  \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries}C{2}|}{Date} &
  \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries}C2|}{Contact} \\ \hline

  \multicolumn{2}{|C2|}{\textit{signature}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{C2|}{\textit{16 Oct 20}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{C2|}{\textit{name@example.edu}} \\ \hline

% ************* Student 2 *************
  \multicolumn{2}{|>{\bfseries}C2|}{%
    Name (Company)\par
    Student 2} &
  \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries}C2|}{Date} &
  \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries}C2|}{Contact} \\ \hline

  \multicolumn{2}{|C2|}{\textit{signature}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{C2|}{\textit{16 Oct 20}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{C2|}{\textit{name@example.edu}} \\ \hline

  \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Approved by:}} \\ \hline

  \multicolumn{2}{|>{\bfseries}C2|}{Name\par Instructor} &
  \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries}C2|}{Date} &
  \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries}C2|}{Contact} \\ \hline

  \multicolumn{2}{|C2|}{\textit{signature}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{C2|}{\textit{23 Oct 20}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{C2|}{\textit{name@example.edu}} \\ \hline

  \multicolumn{6}{|C6|}{\textbf{Distribution Statement}\par
    Distribution xyz\par
    abcdefg\par
    12345} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Note, that I've also moved some | to avoid jumping vertical lines. You should use \multicolumn{…}{|…|}{…} only for the first columns. For all other columns the | should always be after the column declaration. So move the previous | to the declaration of the previous column.
But even with the changes, IMHO this is a very ugly table. You should always avoid vertical lines and reduce the horizontal lines to a minimum using, e.g., package booktabs, maybe something like:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{C{1}XXXXC{1}}

  \toprule
  \multicolumn{6}{>{\bfseries}C6}{TEST REPORT} \\ \midrule

  \textbf{Module} \par
  1 \par
  \textbf{Revision} \par
  Original &
  \multicolumn{4}{C4}{\textbf{TITLE}} &
  \textbf{Course} \par
  1 \par
  \textbf{Page} \par
  1 of 38 \\ 
  \midrule

  \multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{Prepared by:}} \\ \addlinespace

% ************* Student 1 *************
  \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries}C{2}}{%
    Name (Company)\par
    Student 1} &
  \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries}C{2}}{Date} &
  \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries}C2}{Contact} \\

  \multicolumn{2}{C2}{\textit{signature}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{C2}{\textit{16 Oct 20}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{C2}{\textit{name@example.edu}} \\ \addlinespace

% ************* Student 2 *************
  \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries}C2}{%
    Name (Company)\par
    Student 2} &
  \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries}C2}{Date} &
  \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries}C2}{Contact} \\

  \multicolumn{2}{C2}{\textit{signature}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{C2}{\textit{16 Oct 20}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{C2}{\textit{name@example.edu}} \\ \midrule

  \multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{Approved by:}} \\ \addlinespace

  \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries}C2}{Name\par Instructor} &
  \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries}C2}{Date} &
  \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries}C2}{Contact} \\

  \multicolumn{2}{C2}{\textit{signature}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{C2}{\textit{23 Oct 20}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{C2}{\textit{name@example.edu}} \\ \midrule

  \multicolumn{6}{C6}{\textbf{Distribution Statement}\par
    Distribution xyz\par
    abcdefg\par
    12345} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}


But IMHO this is still not the best table design.

Just as a note: With tabular* instead of tabularx the column stretching would work:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{|@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c|c|c|c|c|c|}

\hline

\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{TEST REPORT}} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Module}} &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{TITLE}} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Course}} \\ 

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} & 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2024} \\

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Revision}} &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Page}} \\ 

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Original} & 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1 of 38} \\ 
\hline

\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Prepared by:}} \\ \hline

% ************* Student 1 *************
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Name (Company)}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Date}} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Contact}} \\

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Student 1}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{signature}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{16 Oct 20}} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{name@example.edu}} \\ \hline

% ************* Student 2 *************
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Name (Company)}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Date}} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Contact}} \\

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Student 2}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{signature}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{16 Oct 20}} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{name@example.edu}} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Approved by:}} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Name}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Date}} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Contact}} \\

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Instructor}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{signature}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{23 Oct 20}} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{name@example.edu}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Distribution Statement}} \\

\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Distribution xyz} \\

\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{abcdefg} \\

\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{12345} \\

\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}

But the result is still not the expected one:

The problem here is still, that the extra horizontal space is not added in a proper way because of using all the \multicolumn commands.
An alternative would be to use longtable and it's kill feature:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|*6{p{\dimeval{\linewidth/6-2\tabcolsep}}|}}
& & & & & \kill
\hline

\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{TEST REPORT}} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Module}} &
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{TITLE}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Course}} \\ 

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} & 
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{2024} \\

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Revision}} &
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Page}} \\ 

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Original} & 
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{1 of 38} \\ 
\hline

\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Prepared by:}} \\ \hline

% ************* Student 1 *************
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Name (Company)}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Date}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Contact}} \\

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Student 1}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{signature}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{16 Oct 20}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{name@example.edu}} \\ \hline

% ************* Student 2 *************
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Name (Company)}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Date}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Contact}} \\

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Student 2}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{signature}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{16 Oct 20}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{name@example.edu}} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Approved by:}} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Name}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Date}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Contact}} \\

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Instructor}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{signature}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{23 Oct 20}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{name@example.edu}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Distribution Statement}} \\

\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Distribution xyz} \\

\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{abcdefg} \\

\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{12345} \\

\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}




However, to make it work I have had to include the line & & & & & \\. If I remove the line the table adds an additional column. ... What am I doing wrong?

What you've run into is a rather fundamental, though fortunately rarely encountered shortcoming of some of the very-low-level TeX machinery that's employed to compute the width of the X column type. Basically (the details are gory...), the width of an X column is calculated as a residual, by subtracting the widths of the natural-column-width columns from the overall or target width of the tabularx environment and then dividing by the number of X-type columns. (Often, this target width is \linewidth.)
Now, the unwanted & & & & & \\ line does provide just enough information to let LaTeX compute the widths of each column. However, without this line, only columns 1 and 6 have nontrivial individual contents in some rows. All other rows employ either \multicolumn{2}... or \multicolumn{4}... constructs. It turns out that there just isn't enough independent information present in the table to determine the widths of the grouped cells -- and hence the widths of the individual X-type cells -- uniquely. When this happens, tabularx essentially "gives up" and just uses the natural cell width of the \multicolumn... construct. (If the \multicolumn construct is empty, the resulting column width may even be zero.) And -- as is the case with your particular table -- the difference between the actual and target widths of the tabularx environment may cause LaTeX to insert a random-looking extra column on the right.
What to do? You need to provide explicit width information for at least one row each that contains either 3 \multicolumn{2}... directives or 1 \multicolumn{4}... directive. See below for an implementation of this idea.
Note that I've deleted the useless \multicolumn{1}... wrappers.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of 'X'
\newcolumntype{D}% for 2-column cells
   {>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth \relax}C}
\newcolumntype{E}% for 4-column cells
   {>{\hsize=\dimexpr4\hsize+6\tabcolsep+4\arrayrulewidth \relax}C}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{6}{C|}}

\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{TEST REPORT}} \\ 
\hline
\textbf{Module} &
\multicolumn{4}{ E|}{\textbf{TITLE}} & % don't use 'c' column type
\textbf{Course} \\ 
1 & 
\multicolumn{4}{ c|}{} &
2024 \\[1ex]

\textbf{Revision} &
\multicolumn{4}{ c|}{} & 
\textbf{Page} \\ 
Original & 
\multicolumn{4}{ c|}{} & 
1 of 38 \\ 
\hline

\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Prepared by:}} \\ \hline

% ************* Student 1 *************
\multicolumn{2}{|D|}{\textbf{Name (Company)}} & % don't use 'c' column type
\multicolumn{2}{ D|}{\textbf{Date}} &
\multicolumn{2}{ D|}{\textbf{Contact}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Student 1}} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{} \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{signature}} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\textit{16 Oct 20}} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\textit{name@example.edu}} \\ 
\hline
% ************* Student 2 *************
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Name (Company)}} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\textbf{Date}} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\textbf{Contact}} \\

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Student 2}} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{} \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{signature}} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\textit{16 Oct 20}} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\textit{name@example.edu}} \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Approved by:}} \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Name}} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\textbf{Date}} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\textbf{Contact}} \\

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Instructor}} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{} \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textit{signature}} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\textit{23 Oct 20}} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\textit{name@example.edu}} \\ \hline
%& & & & & \\ % no longer needed
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Distribution Statement}} \\
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Distribution xyz} \\
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{abcdefg} \\
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{12345} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}


this is what I was trying to do ... and couldn't :(.

You may try to write your table using tblr table of tabularray package. Code is quite shorter (and to my opinion simpler):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, 
             colsep  = 3pt,
             colspec = { *{6}{X[c, font=\bfseries]} },
             cell{3-Z}{odd} = {c=2}{},
             hspan   = minimal
             }
\SetCell[c=6]{}     TEST REPORT                 
            &   &   &   &   &                       \\ 
{Module\\  
\normalfont    
1 \\
\textbf{Revision}\\
 original}  &   \SetCell[c=4]{}     TITLE
                &   &   &   &  {Course \\
                                \normalfont 
                                2024 \\
                                \textbf{Page} \\
                                1 -- 38}        \\ 
\SetCell[c=6]{l}     Prepared by:              
            &   &   &   &   &                       \\ 

% ************* Student 1 *************
{Name (Company)\\ Student 1}
            &   &   Date
                    &   &   Contact
                            &                   \\
\textit{signature}
            &   &   \textit{16 Oct 20}
                    &   &   \textit{name@example.edu}
                            &                   \\ 
% ************* Student 2 *************
{Name (Company)\\ Student 2}
            &   &   Date
                    &   &   Contact
                            &                   \\
\SetRow{font=\normalfont}
\textit{signature}
            &   &   \textit{16 Oct 20}
                    &   &   \textit{name@example.edu}
                            &                   \\ 
%%
\SetCell[c=6]{l}     Approved by:                                    \\ 
            &   &   &   &   &                       \\ 
{Name\\ instructor}
            &   &   Date
                    &   &   Contact
                            &                   \\
\SetRow{font=\normalfont}
\textit{signature}
            &   &   \textit{23 Oct 20}
                    &   &   \textit{name@example.edu}
                            &                   \\ 
%& & & & & \\ % no longer needed
\SetCell[c=6]{}         {Distribution Statement\\ 
                          \normalfont 
                         Distribution xyz \\
                         abcdefg \\
                         12345}                 \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}



+1 I knew, you will show this (and usually better than I could). ;-)

@cabohah, oh, thank you for kind words!
